# How to set Field attributes in jinja 2 loop

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am quite new to programming and I need your help. I have a field list of float fields where each one should display a different default value.

I want to change the default attribute by iterating in my template but it's not working.

```html
<div class="form-group">
            {% for entry in form.pde_parameters %}
            {% set entry.default=pde_parameter_value_list[loop.index0]%}
            {{ pde_parameter_list[loop.index0] }}
            {{ entry.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ render_field(entry.parameter_value) }}
            {% endfor %}

</div>
```

```py
class NewModelParameterMaskForm(FlaskForm):
    parameter_value = FloatField("")

class Solution(FlaskForm):
    pde_parameters = FieldList(FormField(NewModelParameterMaskForm), min_entries=1)
    sde_parameters = FieldList(FormField(NewModelParameterMaskForm), min_entries=1)
```

I get this error message:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: cannot assign attribute on non-namespace object

Comment: What is the purpose of the `set` call? I don't see anything about `default` in the code you've provided. `set` is used to declare Jinja2 variables, but you're trying to use it to update an object that's been passed in, so that's likely where the issue lies.

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving the same error. The solution I found would look similar to this in the question's case:

```
{% set update_result = entry.update({'default': pde_parameter_value_list[loop.index0]}) %}
```

Then ignore the `update_result` variable and use the `entry` normally.

It seems Jinja doesn't allow setting directly the value of a field/property inside an object. However, if these are dictionaries or lists, you can use methods like `update` or `append` since they change the object internally.

Answer (score 3):

Just as with the `dict.update` suggestion above, it seems to be possible to trick Jinja into setting attributes by simply calling `__setattr__` on the object:

```py
{% set _ = obj.__setattr__('fieldname', 'value') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate the form *before* you pass it to Jinja, not inside your template.

```
def show_solution():
    form = Solution(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Use form values
        return redirect(url_for('done'))

    for s in solutions(): # Fetch your solutions from somewhere
        form.pde_paramaters.append_entry({'parameter_value': s.float_value})

    return render_template('solution.html', form=form)
```

Comment: You're welcome! If the solution worked for you, I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer.